# Nginx - php-files not found after rewrite

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewriting **/assets/* -> to /theme/theme_1/***.
The rewrite url works with all files except .php-files.

Example file structure:

- /theme/theme_1/images/image.jpg
- /theme/theme_1/images/user.jpg
- /theme/theme_1/ajax/register.php
- /theme/theme_1/ajax/read.php

The problem is the PHP-files, I get a 404 with this url:
wget http://example.com/assets/ajax/read.php. 
File is found (200) using full path http://example.com/theme/theme_1/ajax/read.php

All other file works fine (200):
wget http://example.com/assets/images/image.jpg

nginx config:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;

  root /var/www/html;
  index index.php index.html
  server_name mysite.com;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }

  location /assets {
    rewrite ^/assets/(.*) /theme/theme_1/$1 break;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `last` instead of `break`.

Comment: If that doesn't work then add `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;` to `location /assets {` block also

Comment: Thanks for replying, sorry none of the above worked. I did a quick fix with a symlink. Not the best solution, I'd rather have a nginx-fix :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okie you should try this

```
  location /assets/ {
    alias /var/www/html/theme/theme_1/;
  }
```

If that doesn't work then try

```
  location /assets/ {
    alias /var/www/html/theme/theme_1/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }
```

**Edit-1**

On second look I realize the previous answer won't work as `~ \.php {` block will catch everything with `php` extension and the other `assets` block can never get called. So the solution is to nest the rewrite inside the php block. So use

```
  location ~ \.php$ {
    rewrite ^/assets/(.*)$ /theme/theme_1/$1;

    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, none of the above worked.
I tried some modifications of the settings you sent. Like with or without the rewrite. Full path for try_files etc. I'm stuck with the symlink. Any more ideas?

Comment: The Edit-1 did the trick. Thanks a lot for your help @tarun-lalwani